# Return API in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, api, dictionary, request

I need help with how to return API request in dictionary format in Python Using the New York Times API (specifically Article Search) return news items in
a Python dictionary format.

See developer.nytimes.com For the API documentation of the New York
Times of needed. Tried to find out any useful info but got stuck about how to return calls in Dict Python format

Each result should contain the news results from the NYTimes API as a flattened dictionary. Example for an item (excerpt):

```
{
        "web_url": "http://nytimes.com/...",
        "headline.main": "The main headline",
        "headline.kicker": "...",
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that has been provided by Mahmood R here on StackOverflow

```
r = requests.get(query_url)
filtered = [{'web_url': d['web_url'], 'source': d['source']} for d in
            r.json()['response']['docs']]
pprint(filtered)
```